# Regular expressions -- Match anything other than the capture

Tags: c#, regex

I have been fiddling but I can't quite get the following to work -- I would like to be able to check for the repeated (spammed) use of one character and one character only, in a string of arbitrary length. Using a regular expression, obviously.

`1111111111111` -- should match

`1111111112111` -- should NOT match

`!!!!!!!!!!!!!` -- should match

`!!!!!!a!!!!!!` -- should NOT match

Or vice versa; as in, I am perfectly fine with either a TRUE or FALSE for the result. As long as I can actually get a result. I'm not a reg ex guru, I believed I had it with something along the lines of

```
^.*(.).*(?!\1)$
```

... but, no luck.

Edit (Feb 18th 2015, 11:11 GMT +1):

Partially to end the debate that took place over performance and other such topics on which solution is the best, I decided to benchmark the 3 primary offered solutions; the regular expression, Linq's Distinct() method and Linq's ORDER BY functionality.

The results:

`Generating data (1000 crytopgraphically strong random passwords)......done`

`Testing begins now!`

`Regular expression......done, 1000 iterations took 3033 microseconds`

`string.Distinct......done, 1000 iterations took 10822 microseconds`

`Order by (Linq)......done, 1000 iterations took 13566 microseconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(.)\1*$/gm
```

See Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sP1mQ4/1

Comment: Thanks, that's it indeed. I knew I was close, kind of.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the following to ensure you have a string of repeated characters.

```
^(.)\1*$
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Public Function IsSpam(value As String) As Boolean
    Dim a = From n In value.ToCharArray() Order By n Descending
            Order By n Descending

    Return a(0) = a(a.Count - 1)
End Function
```

Is an alternative to using Regex.